# Oracle ODAC 11.2 installed locally and VS2010 C# app works great but won't work on server with ODAC 11.2 installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, oracle, oracle11g, odac

I've been struggling with this for a few hours and I'm hoping it's something simple I missed. Here's the situation:

1. I built a .Net 4.0 SOAP web service with Visual Studio 2010 and I have the ODAC 11.2 installed locally. It has ODP.Net and everything else installed. See image below.
2. Everything works great running on IIS on my machine locally. Connects to the database, updates, etc. all good.
3. The problem comes when I try and invoke the web service method call on a Windows 2008 IIS 7 server which has ODAC 11.2 installed as well.  The web service just spins.

Any help with debug suggestions are appreciated. I have no administrative access to the server and I've only been provided with a screen shot of the contents of the ODAC installation folder so I can see what's in there. (shown below).

Also putting in my web.config connection string to see if i'm missing something there.

Thanks in advance for anyone who has some ideas for me to get moving forward on this one!!!

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnString" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = **************)(PORT = 1526))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = SDP****)));User Id=SF_WS_USER;Password=********"  />
  </connectionStrings>
```

[image: ODAC Installed locally on my development machine]

[image: Screen Shot of the ODAC folder on the server]

Comment: Try changing the Application Pool to enable loading of 32-bit DLL's.

Comment: Do you have any other apps on the server that work using the same install of ODAC? Also check that it's not a 32-bit vs 64-bit problem.

Comment: Yes, there are other apps that are working but I can't see their source code unfortunately. I did have to enabled 32-bit applications on the app pool, that was the first fix Xenonlightning! :-) I can see that my application is connecting to Oracle but it's erroring on the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() for some reason.

Comment: I figured it out... the problem was the version of the Oracle.DataAccess.dll I was using. Apparently it wasn't matching up with what was on the server and that was causing the issue.  Thanks for taking the time to review guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... the problem was the version of the Oracle.DataAccess.dll I was using in the application. Apparently it wasn't matching up with what was on the server and that was causing the issue. Thanks for taking the time to review guys!